# Deploying c++ project in unix

Tags: unix, eclipse

I'm a new in Unix. I've just created c++ project in Eclipse CDT(Ubuntu 12.04). How can I deploy(install in my machine) this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to configure Eclipse to [produce software packages for Ubuntu](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/packaging/)

> Using a Personal Package Archive (PPA), you can distribute software and updates directly to Ubuntu users. Create your source package, upload it and Launchpad will build binaries and then host them in your own apt repository.
>
> That means Ubuntu users can install your packages in just the same way they install standard Ubuntu packages and they'll automatically receive updates as and when you make them.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to put your executable in:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

This is parsed for executable command as default (a.k.a $PATH). Anyway if you put in any folder which is in the $PATH, every user who has read/execute access on it (/usr/local/bin is like that), will be able just to type on the command line

```
$ <your_executable_name>
```

And your program will run ( don't forget to restart the terminal to parse this ). If you look for other ways to start this program e.g.: from some kind of start menu like gnomes, then you can just add an entry and there should be an option to add an execution command for this entry ( where you will need to enter the executables name ).

You can easly print your current $PATH by:

```
echo $PATH
```

Where the : character is a separtor for the used folders. You can add a directory to the $PATH by:

```
export PATH="<your_directory>:$PATH"
```